# Cannot configure OpenSSL on Windows properly

Tags: windows, qt, soap, openssl, hsm

I want to use KDSoap, which uses Qt, which uses OpenSSL, to consume a web service, that requires a secure connection, established by using a key stored in a USB HSM (SmartCard + Reader basically, called an Athena IDProtect Key v2.0).

I've installed 64bit OpenSSL from [Shining Light Productions](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Qt 5.8 can load it (I've checked with `QSslSocket`).

### Problem

The problem is that even though [it seems](https://blogs.kde.org/2012/04/14/whats-new-qt-5-ssl) that Qt's network backend should load the OpenSSL config file, it does not. In fact, I think OpenSSL is to blame here and not Qt because of the tests I've done with the provided openssl tool.

First of all, the config is read because any syntax error in the config makes the openssl tool complain about it next time I run it.
Second of all, with a clean config, this works:

```
C:\Users\brokenthorn>openssl engine dynamic -t -pre SO_PATH:C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\capi.dll -pre LOAD  -post list_certs
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
[Success]: SO_PATH:C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\capi.dll
[Success]: LOAD
Loaded: (capi) CryptoAPI ENGINE
    [ available ]
Certificate 0
<No Friendly Name>
Subject: C = RO, L = Mun. Constanta, O = SC MINI-FARM SRL, CN = Valentina Calin, serialNumber = 2006051670CV93, name = Valentina Calin, GN = Valentina, SN = Calin
Issuer: C = RO, O = certSIGN, OU = certSIGN Qualified CA Class 3 G2, CN = certSIGN Qualified CA Class 3 G2
Certificate 1
<No Friendly Name>
Subject: CN = DESKTOP-IF670KN\\brokenthorn
Issuer: CN = DESKTOP-IF670KN\\brokenthorn
[Success]: list_certs
```

But if I try to load the engine by ID, after having defined it in the config file, I get an error where it says it cannot find the DLL file, except it adds `.dll.dll` to the specified ID:

```
OpenSSL> engine -t -pre ID:capi -pre LOAD
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
[Success]: ID:capi
[Failure]: LOAD
4684:error:25078067:DSO support routines:WIN32_LOAD:could not load the shared library:.\crypto\dso\dso_win32.c:179:filename(capi.dll.dll)
4684:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:.\crypto\dso\dso_lib.c:233:
4684:error:260B6084:engine routines:DYNAMIC_LOAD:dso not found:.\crypto\engine\eng_dyn.c:467:
    [ unavailable ]
```

Now, I've tried creating a copy of `capi.dll` and named it `capi.dll.dll` and the above command starts working:

```
OpenSSL> engine -t -pre ID:capi -pre LOAD
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
[Success]: ID:capi
[Success]: LOAD
Loaded: (capi) CryptoAPI ENGINE
    [ available ]
```

My `openssl.cfg` is standard except the last part, where've I added the engine directives that should make OpenSSL load the CryptoAPI engine by default, which I need if I'm ever going to be able to open a secure socket using the key stored on the HSM. I'll paste the full config here for a full reference, in case something bad sticks out:

```
#
# OpenSSL example configuration file.
# This is mostly being used for generation of certificate requests.
#

# This definition stops the following lines choking if HOME isn't
# defined.
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

# Extra OBJECT IDENTIFIER info:
#oid_file       = $ENV::HOME/.oid
oid_section     = new_oids

# To use this configuration file with the "-extfile" option of the
# "openssl x509" utility, name here the section containing the
# X.509v3 extensions to use:
# extensions        = 
# (Alternatively, use a configuration file that has only
# X.509v3 extensions in its main [= default] section.)

[ new_oids ]

# We can add new OIDs in here for use by 'ca', 'req' and 'ts'.
# Add a simple OID like this:
# testoid1=1.2.3.4
# Or use config file substitution like this:
# testoid2=${testoid1}.5.6

# Policies used by the TSA examples.
tsa_policy1 = 1.2.3.4.1
tsa_policy2 = 1.2.3.4.5.6
tsa_policy3 = 1.2.3.4.5.7

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

####################################################################
[ CA_default ]

dir     = ./demoCA      # Where everything is kept
certs       = $dir/certs        # Where the issued certs are kept
crl_dir     = $dir/crl      # Where the issued crl are kept
database    = $dir/index.txt    # database index file.
#unique_subject = no            # Set to 'no' to allow creation of
                    # several ctificates with same subject.
new_certs_dir   = $dir/newcerts     # default place for new certs.

certificate = $dir/cacert.pem   # The CA certificate
serial      = $dir/serial       # The current serial number
crlnumber   = $dir/crlnumber    # the current crl number
                    # must be commented out to leave a V1 CRL
crl     = $dir/crl.pem      # The current CRL
private_key = $dir/private/cakey.pem# The private key
RANDFILE    = $dir/private/.rand    # private random number file

x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extentions to add to the cert

# Comment out the following two lines for the "traditional"
# (and highly broken) format.
name_opt    = ca_default        # Subject Name options
cert_opt    = ca_default        # Certificate field options

# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions = copy

# Extensions to add to a CRL. Note: Netscape communicator chokes on V2 CRLs
# so this is commented out by default to leave a V1 CRL.
# crlnumber must also be commented out to leave a V1 CRL.
# crl_extensions    = crl_ext

default_days    = 365           # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = default       # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

# A few difference way of specifying how similar the request should look
# For type CA, the listed attributes must be the same, and the optional
# and supplied fields are just that :-)
policy      = policy_match

# For the CA policy
[ policy_match ]
countryName     = match
stateOrProvinceName = match
organizationName    = match
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

# For the 'anything' policy
# At this point in time, you must list all acceptable 'object'
# types.
[ policy_anything ]
countryName     = optional
stateOrProvinceName = optional
localityName        = optional
organizationName    = optional
organizationalUnitName  = optional
commonName      = supplied
emailAddress        = optional

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 2048
default_keyfile     = privkey.pem
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
attributes      = req_attributes
x509_extensions = v3_ca # The extentions to add to the self signed cert

# Passwords for private keys if not present they will be prompted for
# input_password = secret
# output_password = secret

# This sets a mask for permitted string types. There are several options. 
# default: PrintableString, T61String, BMPString.
# pkix   : PrintableString, BMPString (PKIX recommendation before 2004)
# utf8only: only UTF8Strings (PKIX recommendation after 2004).
# nombstr : PrintableString, T61String (no BMPStrings or UTF8Strings).
# MASK:XXXX a literal mask value.
# WARNING: ancient versions of Netscape crash on BMPStrings or UTF8Strings.
string_mask = utf8only

# req_extensions = v3_req # The extensions to add to a certificate request

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_default     = AU
countryName_min         = 2
countryName_max         = 2

stateOrProvinceName     = State or Province Name (full name)
stateOrProvinceName_default = Some-State

localityName            = Locality Name (eg, city)

0.organizationName      = Organization Name (eg, company)
0.organizationName_default  = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd

# we can do this but it is not needed normally :-)
#1.organizationName     = Second Organization Name (eg, company)
#1.organizationName_default = World Wide Web Pty Ltd

organizationalUnitName      = Organizational Unit Name (eg, section)
#organizationalUnitName_default =

commonName          = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
commonName_max          = 64

emailAddress            = Email Address
emailAddress_max        = 64

# SET-ex3           = SET extension number 3

[ req_attributes ]
challengePassword       = A challenge password
challengePassword_min       = 4
challengePassword_max       = 20

unstructuredName        = An optional company name

[ usr_cert ]

# These extensions are added when 'ca' signs a request.

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This is required for TSA certificates.
# extendedKeyUsage = critical,timeStamping

[ v3_req ]

# Extensions to add to a certificate request

basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

[ v3_ca ]


# Extensions for a typical CA


# PKIX recommendation.

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash

authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer

# This is what PKIX recommends but some broken software chokes on critical
# extensions.
#basicConstraints = critical,CA:true
# So we do this instead.
basicConstraints = CA:true

# Key usage: this is typical for a CA certificate. However since it will
# prevent it being used as an test self-signed certificate it is best
# left out by default.
# keyUsage = cRLSign, keyCertSign

# Some might want this also
# nsCertType = sslCA, emailCA

# Include email address in subject alt name: another PKIX recommendation
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# Copy issuer details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

# DER hex encoding of an extension: beware experts only!
# obj=DER:02:03
# Where 'obj' is a standard or added object
# You can even override a supported extension:
# basicConstraints= critical, DER:30:03:01:01:FF

[ crl_ext ]

# CRL extensions.
# Only issuerAltName and authorityKeyIdentifier make any sense in a CRL.

# issuerAltName=issuer:copy
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always

[ proxy_cert_ext ]
# These extensions should be added when creating a proxy certificate

# This goes against PKIX guidelines but some CAs do it and some software
# requires this to avoid interpreting an end user certificate as a CA.

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

# Here are some examples of the usage of nsCertType. If it is omitted
# the certificate can be used for anything *except* object signing.

# This is OK for an SSL server.
# nsCertType            = server

# For an object signing certificate this would be used.
# nsCertType = objsign

# For normal client use this is typical
# nsCertType = client, email

# and for everything including object signing:
# nsCertType = client, email, objsign

# This is typical in keyUsage for a client certificate.
# keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment

# This will be displayed in Netscape's comment listbox.
nsComment           = "OpenSSL Generated Certificate"

# PKIX recommendations harmless if included in all certificates.
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer

# This stuff is for subjectAltName and issuerAltname.
# Import the email address.
# subjectAltName=email:copy
# An alternative to produce certificates that aren't
# deprecated according to PKIX.
# subjectAltName=email:move

# Copy subject details
# issuerAltName=issuer:copy

#nsCaRevocationUrl      = http://www.domain.dom/ca-crl.pem
#nsBaseUrl
#nsRevocationUrl
#nsRenewalUrl
#nsCaPolicyUrl
#nsSslServerName

# This really needs to be in place for it to be a proxy certificate.
proxyCertInfo=critical,language:id-ppl-anyLanguage,pathlen:3,policy:foo

####################################################################
[ tsa ]

default_tsa = tsa_config1   # the default TSA section

[ tsa_config1 ]

# These are used by the TSA reply generation only.
dir     = ./demoCA      # TSA root directory
serial      = $dir/tsaserial    # The current serial number (mandatory)
crypto_device   = builtin       # OpenSSL engine to use for signing
signer_cert = $dir/tsacert.pem  # The TSA signing certificate
                    # (optional)
certs       = $dir/cacert.pem   # Certificate chain to include in reply
                    # (optional)
signer_key  = $dir/private/tsakey.pem # The TSA private key (optional)

default_policy  = tsa_policy1       # Policy if request did not specify it
                    # (optional)
other_policies  = tsa_policy2, tsa_policy3  # acceptable policies (optional)
digests     = md5, sha1     # Acceptable message digests (mandatory)
accuracy    = secs:1, millisecs:500, microsecs:100  # (optional)
clock_precision_digits  = 0 # number of digits after dot. (optional)
ordering        = yes   # Is ordering defined for timestamps?
                # (optional, default: no)
tsa_name        = yes   # Must the TSA name be included in the reply?
                # (optional, default: no)
ess_cert_id_chain   = no    # Must the ESS cert id chain be included?
                # (optional, default: no)

# 
# Custom configuration for definition of CAPI engine
# 
openssl_conf = openssl_init

[openssl_init]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
capi = capi_config

[capi_config]
ID = capi
SO_PATH = C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\capi.dll
LIST_ADD = 1
LOAD = 1
```

Now, OpenSSL should load the `capi` engine by default on library initialisation, which happens in every app that links with this OpenSSL (and does not call special routines that unload or disable loading of the default config file), including the `openssl` command line tool.

I don't know how yet, but eventually I should also make it the default crypto provider.

Anyways, after adding the above config and also before that, of course, I get this:

```
OpenSSL> engine -t
(rdrand) Intel RDRAND engine
    [ available ]
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
    [ unavailable ]
```

This shouldn't happen. The `dynamic` engine should have *morphed* into the `capi` engine... like the OpenSSL docs say.

Also the CSP for the HSM works. I can list the loaded CSPs like so:

```
C:\Users\brokenthorn>openssl engine dynamic -t -pre SO_PATH:C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\capi.dll -pre LOAD -post list_csps
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
[Success]: SO_PATH:C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\capi.dll
[Success]: LOAD
Loaded: (capi) CryptoAPI ENGINE
    [ available ]
Available CSPs:
0. Athena ASECard Crypto CSP, type 1
1. Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0, type 1
2. Microsoft Base DSS and Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider, type 13
3. Microsoft Base DSS Cryptographic Provider, type 3
4. Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider, type 1
5. Microsoft DH SChannel Cryptographic Provider, type 18
6. Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0, type 1
7. Microsoft Enhanced DSS and Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider, type 13
8. Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider, type 24
9. Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider, type 12
10. Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider, type 1
11. OpenSC CSP, type 1
[Success]: list_csps
```

CSP index 0 is my HSM's CSP. I've also sent a few simple commands using the openssl tool, to the HSM, to confirm that it actually works and it does as it should (it's a vendor supplied CSP provider for CAPI).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this may have been a bad migration. I wish the Stack Exchange policy of one site telling another site what's on-topic for the second site would end. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Both specialize in commands and interacting with the system, but I've got a feeling U&L.SE would be the better choice.

Comment: @e-sushi - Check out the message for the migration. I kind of feel like it could be improved since Crypto.SE is not really looking for a strong intersection with software. Maybe something like the following raises the bar and steps away from software a tad bit: *"This question came from our site for security engineers and architects, mathematicians and others interested in cryptography"*.

Comment: For Windows and OpenSSL CONF problems, follow [OpenSSL and error in reading openssl.conf file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7360602/608639) and the linked questions. OpenSSL can be a bastard on Windows because OpenSSL exports functions by *Ordinal*, not *Name* (Microsoft recommends the latter). It causes a lot of ABI breaks as different projects, like Apache and Shining Light, supply different versions of OpenSSL. OpenSSL rejected the request to export by name.

Comment: @jww Really? What a mess! Seriously, they should think more about developer productivity and not about absolute performance or whatever the reason might have been. Anyways, I've switched to a different route since I've started wrestling with OpenSSL two weeks ago. It took me only one day to build Mozilla's NSS for Windows 10, including fixing the build environment Mozilla provides to build with Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools + Win10 SDK, and not the build docs suggested (required!) full-fledged mastodon that is Visual Studio 2015 + Win8.1 SDK.

Comment: @jww Also, I don't think there's an ABI issue here.